# show multiple charts in a row in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I was wondering if there is a way to show multiple charts in one row in Crystal report based on the group you are in . I am putting my chart in a group footer,and the group is based on commodity like water, electricity, etc.

The normal operation is showing the multiple charts for different commodities vertically, is there a way to force the crystal report to show the charts for different commodities in one row horizontally? ( as you could do it in excel)

appreciate anyone's help

Answer (score 0):

If you place in group it will show vertically it is the functionality of crystal report but there is one way but that is a bit complicated and not sugested

```
Place individual charts for commodites and check the option `Underlay following sections` in section expert for group footer
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this technique will do but i used it to display record horizontally

1. Right clicked details area
2. select section expert
3. on common tab, check Format with Multiple Columns
4. A layout tab will added, then click it
5. Set/change the value of the fields

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks. but this does not work for me as i am having the chart in the group footer, and you don't have that Format with Multiple Columns option in the group footer , it is only on details section